# What pun is intended in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pun

I was reading [a technical article](https://gregoryszorc.com/blog/2017/03/07/better-compression-with-zstandard/#:%7E:text=On%20one%20end%2C%20zstd%20level,that%20is%20only%202.3%25%20larger.) and came across the "pun intended" part. I'm not sure what the pun is in this excerpt. What pun is intended in the sentence in bold?

> Being at least 27 years old, DEFLATE is getting a bit long in the
> tooth. Computers are completely different today than they were in
> 1990. The Pentium microprocessor debuted in 1993. **If memory serves (pun intended)**, it used PC66 DRAM, which had a transfer rate of 533
> MB/s. For comparison, a modern NVMe M.2 SSD (like the Samsung 960 PRO)
> can read at 3000+ MB/s and write at 2000+ MB/s.

Comment: I rather suspect the ***only*** reason for writing ***if memory serves*** was for the sake of the pun! It really is true that the *theoretical* (never achieved *in practice*) maximum transfer rate for PD66 DRAM was 533MB/s. But I bet any money the writer never actually dug that number out of his "wetware" memory - he probably [looked it up on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_dynamic_random-access_memory#PC66), same as I just did! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica but the author could dug "pc66" out of the memory (no pun).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pun is in "memory".

It's an allusion to "if memory serves me right" which means "if I remember (something) correctly". And here it also means a physical computer memory, RAM.

Answer (score 1):

> If (my) memory serves (correctly/right/rightly)

means

> If I remember correctly/accurately

which refers to author's memory. They are trying to recall the history of the Pentium microprocessor mentioning PC66 DRAM, which is another kind of memory, a computer one.

Answer (score 1):

["If **memory** serves" means "If I remember accurately"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/if%20memory%20serves), and the excerpt from the article you have linked mentions the PC66 [DRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory), which is a type of computer **memory** unit.